# How to add a log file and logging to it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, logging

Okay so I've gone about so many online instructions on how to add a log file but none of them seem to log anything when i use the command:

```
 logger hello world
```

I added a log file local3.log as follows in

```
/var/log/local3.log
```

now I wanted to log all local3 facility with all severities to it. I went about what some sites told me and went into /etc/rsyslog.conf and added the line:

```
 local3.*         /var/log/local3.log
```

but when anything boots up or any logger commands i give it doesn't update with the time and date and all that. I've already set my logrotate file properly with weekly every 8 weeks and create and dateext. I still can't get it to work I'm thinking I'm editing the wrong syslog file or the wrong command to it?

Comment: and just to clear a couple things i've already service rsyslog restart and reload still didn't work, and i even restarted my vm totally.

Comment: Take a look at loggers option `-p`.

Comment: but will that make it permenant if i type logger -p local3.info ? So that every message after that will go to the local3.log ? tried it didn't work.